# split PATH variable INTO few lines

Tags: bash, path, profile

I have split my PATH variable into few lines, in the file to make them easier to read because it's very long,
as I had seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579849/can-long-path-be-split-across-many-lines).
This is what I changed in my `/etc/profile`:

```
#  PATH="/usr/share/python-wheels:/usr/share/gcc/python/usr/lib/python3/dist-pa>
#  PATH="/usr/share/doc:/usr/lib/python3:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/cups/backend:usr/lib/python3.11:/usr/src/python3.11:/sbin:/bin"

path+=(
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
/home/lm/local/pipx/venvs/esptool
/usr/share/python-wheels
/usr/share/gcc/python
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pygments/lexers
/usr/share/doc
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/cups/backend
/usr/lib/python3.11
/usr/src/python3.11
/sbin
/bin
)
export PATH
```

Then I ran

```
source ~/.profile
```

and `echo $PATH` has not changed:

```
root@debian:/home/lm# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin

root@debian:/etc/default# source /etc/profile
root@debian:/etc/default# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin
```

even after restart XFCE OR after reboot PATH still default value.

What's wrong and how can I fix this for PATH new settings will be accepted?

my system is Debian 12 and XFCE

Comment: Note that the SO question is tagged [tag:zsh], the `path` array synchronised with `$PATH` is a zsh feature.

Comment: does it mean, that i can't split it in bash, or how i can do it?

Comment: ```
root@debian:/etc/default# source /etc/profile

    root@debian:/etc/default# echo $PATH

      / usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games: /usr/games:/home/lm/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want here. Is it just about the format of your `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile` files? Why do you want to split it into many lines, where do you want to have it split? Only in the files to make them easier to read? Only when you print the variable in a terminal?

Comment: Only in the files to make them easier to read

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are using bash, `path` isn't a thing. Bash only has `PATH`. Now, if you just want to format your shell configuration files to be easier to read, you can do something like this:

```bash
path_dirs=(
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
/home/lm/local/pipx/venvs/esptool
/usr/share/python-wheels
/usr/share/gcc/python
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pygments/lexers
/usr/share/doc
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/cups/backend
/usr/lib/python3.11
/usr/src/python3.11
/sbin
/bin
)

for path in "${path_dirs[@]}"; do
  PATH="$PATH:$path"
done
export PATH
```

That just creates an array, `path_dirs`, storing the names of the directories you want in your `PATH`. Then, you iterate over this array and append each entry to the `PATH`.

Note that if any of your directories contains a space, it will need to be quoted:

```
path_dirs=(
...
"/some/path/with a space/"
...
)
```

Also, you cannot add directories whose name contains a newline, but as far as I know, you cannot do that anyway.

Finally, you might want to also use a function like `pathmunge` which, I think, is something that ships with Red Hat/Fedora systems. In any case, I have had it in my `~/.profile` for almost 20 years now and it is very handy:

```
pathmunge () {
        if ! echo $PATH | /bin/grep -Eq "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
           if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
              PATH=$PATH:$1
           else
              PATH=$1:$PATH
           fi
        fi
}
```

The function checks if something is already present in the path and, if it isn't, it adds it to either the beginning or the end of the `PATH` variable. Paste the function into your `~/.profile` file, and then you can run:

```
## add a directory to the beginning of the path (prepend)
pathmunge /some/dir after
## add a directory to the end of the path (append)
pathmunge /some/dir
```

This means that you could change your `~/.profile` to just have:

```
for path in "${path_dirs[@]}"; do
  pathmunge "$path" after
done
```

Comment: in debian repositories pathmunge application say "E: Unable to locate package pathmunge"

Comment: @ant `pathmunge` isn’t a package, it’s just a shell function.

Comment: @terdon if `PATH` is empty before your `for` loop, the result will have an empty entry in first position, and that represents the current directory.

Comment: @StephenKitt hmm yes, true, but since this is `~/.profile` it should be exceedingly unlikely that PATH be empty. But yes, fair point. I'm not at my computer now but I'll see if I can fix that tomorrow.

Comment: That's not a very pretty examples, especially the `for` loop.  I find this to be a little more elegant: `printf -v almost_path '%s:' "${path_dirs[@]}"; PATH="${almost_path%:}"`  --  just my opinion, though

Answer (score 0):

`path` and `PATH` are not inherently the same thing.

Also, /etc/profile content should really be /bin/sh compatible, and this isn't. I'm afraid none of this works like you want. Try this: copy the code you have and run `sh` from your terminal, paste the code, inspect `$path` and `$PATH$.

Comment: The `$path` array is tied to the `$PATH` scalar in csh, tcsh or zsh. The OP's code is in `zsh` syntax (`var=(...)`, `var+=(...)` are from `zsh`, `source` is from `csh`), but `/etc/profile` should be in a syntax compatible with all the shells that read it, not in zsh-specific (or bash-specific, ksh-specific...) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with "colon-separated" lists (`PATH` is one example) I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path. `listpath` lists a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Comment: Many examples of what **not** to do in those linuxjournal articles like that `eval opt_$argname=$OPTARG`  in https://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/036/3645/3645l2.html which is wrong on so many levels.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is zsh specific. `/etc/profile` is a system-wide (so for every user) *session* initialisation file interpreted by Bourne-like shells when invoked as *login* shells (with `-` as the first character of their 0<sup>th</sup> argument).

`zsh` itself only reads it when in `sh` or `ksh` emulation like when invoked with `-sh` or `-ksh` as the 0<sup>th</sup> argument.

So that file should be in `sh` syntax. POSIX `sh` syntax should do except maybe on systems that still have a Bourne shell, though that's very rare in this day and age.

Nowadays though, login sessions are more often than not graphical ones, and `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` are rarely used to set the environment. You may have more luck with things like `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.pam_environment`.

Now to add elements to `$PATH` in POSIX sh syntax, you could define a function such as:

```
add_to_PATH() for _dir do
  case ":$PATH:" in
    (*:"$_dir":*) ;; # already there
    (*) PATH="$PATH${PATH:+:}$_dir";;
  esac
done

add_to_PATH     \
  /my/dir       \
  /my/other/dir \
  ...
```

That syntax is also `zsh`-compatible (though obviously there are easier ways to do it in `zsh`) and `bash`-compatible (most POSIX `sh` code is bash-compatible as `bash` has much fewer deviations from the standard than `zsh`), so that code can be read by either of those shells as well as all POSIX-compatible ones.

The only thing that is not Bourne-compatible in there is the `(*:"$_dir":*)` and `(*)` which would need to be changed to `*:"$_dir":*)` and `*)` (and with older versions of the Bourne shell, `# comments` which were a csh-only thing initially (up to the mid-80s)).